# Using regex to match words and numbers with whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to create a regex pattern that would match the following:

```
Updated x word word
```

`x` = being a number, e.g. 2

I have tried the following:

```
(Updated\s\d\s\w\s\w)
```

For example, I would like: `Updated 2 mins ago`, to match.

But it doesn't seem to work: http://regexr.com/3ef05

Comment: does the order of numbers/words matter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to show that the digit and word groups can consist of more than one character:

```
(Updated\s\d+\s\w+\s\w+)
```

This works: http://regexr.com/3ef08

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
(Updated\s\d+\s\w+\s\w+)
```

The `+` means "one or more characters of this type", which is probably what you need here.

See it here : http://regexr.com/3ef0b